# Assume that there is a test for cancer that is 90% accurate for both those who do and do not have cancer.

Tags: probability

Assume that there is a test for cancer that is 90% accurate for both those who do and do not have cancer. Also assume that 5% of the population has cancer. If an individual takes this test and tests positive for cancer, find the probability that they really do have cancer?

- For this problem, I did a tree diagram with population on top then split it into 5% cancer and 95% no cancer. Then I split the 5% into 90% positive test and 10% negative test. Finally I split the 95% into 10% positive test and 90% negative. However, I feel like I'm off somewhere and I do not know how to continue from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there are 4 cases:

- $5\%$ cancer

  1. $90\%$ positive test (total weight $0.05 \cdot 0.9 = 0.045$)
  2. $10\%$ negative test (total weight $0.05 \cdot 0.1 = 0.005$)
- $95\%$ no cancer

  1. $10\%$ positive test (total weight $0.95 \cdot 0.1 = 0.095$)
  2. $90\%$ negative test (total weight $0.95 \cdot 0.9 = 0.855$)

Now, when a person tests positive for cancer, this is possible in one of two ways:

- he really had cancer and tested positive, with weight $0.045$
- he didn't have cancer and tested positive, with weight $0.095$

So what is the total probability of him actually being sick?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but would I add those probabilities to get 0.14 then do (0.05)(0.90) / 0.14 so the answer would be 0.32143?

Comment: @Sam this is correct, but your last probability is rounded, not sure how many decimal points you actually need. the correct answer is $0.045/0.14 = 9/28$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give names to the events.

Event A: Test positive for cancer

Event B: Individual has cancer

Just apply Bayes' rule:
$P(B|A) = \dfrac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a contingency table rather than a tree diagram.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Test Positive} & \text{Test Negative} & \\
\hline
\text{Has Cancer} & a & b & a + b \\
\hline
\text{No Cancer} & c & d & c + d \\
\hline
& a+c & b+d & a+b+c+d \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

We are told that $95\%$ of the population does not have cancer, and $5\%$ does.  So let's pick $a+b+c+d = 1000$ people in our population; then $a+b = (0.05)(1000) = 50$, and $c+d = 950$.  Of those with cancer, the test is positive $90\%$ of the time, thus $a = (0.90)(50) = 45$, and $b = 5$.   Similarly, of those who do not have cancer, the test is negative $90\%$ of the time, so $d = (0.9)(950) = 855$, and $c = 950 - 855 = 95$.  So the table looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Test Positive} & \text{Test Negative} & \\
\hline
\text{Has Cancer} & 45 & 5 & 50 \\
\hline
\text{No Cancer} & 95 & 855 & 950 \\
\hline
& 140 & 860 & 1000 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Now, how do we use this to answer the question?  If an individual tests positive, they are among the $140$ people in the table.  Of these, how many actually have cancer?  $45$.